# why is $\cos x + i \sin x = i^\frac{x}{90^\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

I was calculating $\sqrt{i}$ and $\sqrt[3]{i}$,

and I found out that in both of those cases,
$\cos x + i \sin x = i^\frac{x}{90}$
this formula is right.
and this formula is right on x=0,30,45,90,360
But  I can't prove it.
Can anybody prove this?

Comment: Just because the formula is right for a couple values doesn't mean its correct for all values.

Comment: The way you state the question seems false. However I believe $\cos x+i\sin x=i^{2x/\pi}$ is true.

Comment: $\log i = i { \pi \over 2}$. You are using degrees on one side and radians in the other,

Comment: I think OP has $x$ in degrees, not radians.

Comment: By the usual definition of powers of complex numbers using the main branch of $\ln$ with complex argument in the range $[0, 2\pi)$, we have $i^\theta = \exp (\theta \ln i) = \exp (\pi i \theta/2) = \cos (\pi \theta/2) + i \sin (\pi \theta/2)$ if $\theta$ is measured in radians, which is equivalent to the OP's formula in degrees.

Comment: @ConnorHarris You might put that in an answer.

Comment: @Couchy311 your formula is wrong at x=45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT it seems I cannot divide fractions correctly, I have updated my answer**

We first start with what you have (I switched to radians though)

$$
i^{\frac{2x}{\pi}} = e^{\frac{2x}{\pi}\log i}
$$

using the complex log definition we know, assuming we are working on just one rotation of the unit circle $[0,2\pi)$

$$
\log i = \log(1) + i\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$

so we get that

$$
i^{\frac{2x}{\pi}} = e^{i\frac{2x}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2}} = e^{ix}
$$

which by Euler's identity is

$$
\cos(x)+i\sin(x)
$$

thus proving your identity Q.E.D

Answer (score 2):

Powers of complex numbers are typically defined using the main branch of $\ln$ with complex argument in the range $[0, 2\pi)$, as $$i^\theta = \exp (\theta \ln i) = \exp \left(\frac{i\pi \theta}{2}\right) = \cos \left(\frac{\pi \theta}{2}\right) + i \sin \left(\frac{\pi \theta}{2}\right)$$ where the argument to the trigonometric functions is in radians. This is equivalent to your formula with arguments in degrees.